# python regular expression to get date and price from a list of string (texts)

Tags: python, regex

Thanks for help in advance
I have a list of strings like

```
ID1|0|1|;2;2;2;5;12/11/2020;3;10.0000;5;06/11/2021;3;9.0000;|
ID2|0|1|;2;2;2;5;1/11/2020;3;11.0000;5;1/11/2021;3;12.0000; |
.
.
```

I am iterating over each item in the list and using RegExp to create a data frame which will be like bellow

```
1D1   12/11/2020  10.0000
1D1   06/11/2021  9.0000
1D2   1/11/2020  11.0000
1D2   1/11/2021  12.0000
```

So far I have able to get the ID and Date . But not sure what pattern to use for price and convert them back to data frame

```
        date_reg_exp = re.compile(r'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}')
        price_reg_exp =re.compile(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+')
        for data_row in self._data:
            bbg_id =(data_row.split('|')[0])
            date_list = [x.group() for x in date_reg_exp.finditer(data_row)]
            price_list =[x.group() for x in price_reg_exp.finditer(data_row)]
```

Comment: Why are you using an RE at all?  Split the each line on `|`.  ID is element 0, data is element 3.  Split data on `;`.  You have dates at element 5 and 9 and floating points (prices?) at 7 and 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex may be hard work.  If the string can be split look into that first.

> I am iterating over each item in the list...

So it is a list then.

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

# given a list like...
ll = ['ID1|0|1|;2;2;2;5;12/11/2020;3;10.0000;5;06/11/2021;3;9.0000;|',
     'ID2|0|1|;2;2;2;5;1/11/2020;3;11.0000;5;1/11/2021;3;12.0000; |']

# create three lists to hold id, date, and price
ids = []
dates = []
prices = []

# split the list and extract the information
for l in ll:
    for s in l.split('|'):
        if 'ID' in s:
            i = s
        if ';' in s:
            for x in s.split(';'):
                if '/' in x:
                    dates.append(x)
                    ids.append(i)
                if '.' in x:
                    prices.append(x)
                    
# create a dataframe and set date to the correct format
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ids, 'date': dates, 'price': prices})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# check the frame
print(df)

    id       date    price
0  ID1 2020-11-12  10.0000
1  ID1 2021-11-06   9.0000
2  ID2 2020-11-01  11.0000
3  ID2 2021-11-01  12.0000
```

Comment: thanks a lot . Makes sense to use split over re

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
txt = "ID1|0|1|;2;2;2;5;12/11/2020;3;10.0000;5;06/11/2021;3;9.0000;|"

x = txt.split("|")
y = x[3].split(";")

print(x[0] + " " + y[5] + " " + y[7])
```

I get the following:

```
ID1 12/11/2020 10.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
```

As @Tibrogargan notes, string splitting is a much better idea. However, the question asked for a regex, so here goes...

```py
price_regex = re.compile('(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4});\d+;(\d+\.\d{4})')
```

This [matches both your test-cases](https://regex101.com/r/oCymgl/1); now just iterate over the lines that match:

```py
for res in price_regex.findall(string):
    if len(res) != 2:
        continue
    date, price = res # do what you want with these
```